# How can the outside modification of an instance variable be hindered in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, private

My understanding was that there are not really private methods/attributes in Python, meaning that as long as you know the name of the method or attribute you will always be able to access and/or modify it (I might be understanding wrongly the concept of privacy).

Taking into account the framework described above, I came across with a situation I cannot quite wrap my head around. When creating a `matplotlib.pyplot` plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(100)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='sinus')
ax.legend()
```

I get a `matplotlib.legend.Legend` object holding a list of all `matplotlib.text.Text` objects that resemble the text entries displayed in the legend:

```
>>> fig.axes[0].legend()
<matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x28f6aa4d898>
>>> fig.axes[0].legend().get_texts()
<a list of 1 Text objects>
>>> fig.axes[0].legend().get_texts()[0]
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x28f6aa17198>
>>> print(fig.axes[0].legend().get_texts()[0])
Text(0,0,'sinus')
```

According to the source code, seems to me that the list returned by the method `matplotlib.legend.Legend.get_texts()` is filled with the content of the `matplotlib.legend.Legend` instance variable `self.texts`, which is itself a list. Accessing and modifying this instance variable does not work:

```
>>> fig.axes[0].legend().texts
[<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x28f6420db38>]
>>> print(fig.axes[0].legend().texts[0])
Text(0,0,'sinus')
>>> fig.axes[0].legend().texts = [matplotlib.text.Text(0,0,'foo')]
>>> print(fig.axes[0].legend().texts[0])
Text(0,0,'sinus')
```

I am not an expert in Python, but I was not expecting this behavior, and I do not understand how this happens at an object/property level, and I haven't followed deeper if there are any special constraints in the construction of the `matplotlib.legend.Legend.texts` instance variable.

The only general reason for this to happen I could come up with has been that at some level of depth there is some kind of "ghost" setter that just does not modify a class property:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def x(self): 
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        # This setter blocks outside access
        pass
```

This setter blocks control from the outside to modify the variable value:

```
>>> f = Foo(3)
>>> f.x
3
f.x = 5
>>> f.x
3
```

Nevertheless, the `matplotlib.legend.Legend` instance variable `self.texts` seems defined like a regular instance variable and I have not been able to find it defined as a property or any getters or setters related to it.

So, given this situation, I have three questions:

1) Is this little class example an accepted/legit way of getting "some sort" of privacy, in the sense that the attribute cannot be modified?

2) Are there some other/equivalent ways of blocking access/control over attributes or methods in Python?

3) How does it work or is it arranged in the particular case of `matplotlib.legend.Legend` objects (focus on the `self.texts` instance variable)?

Considerations:

1) I have tried to find answers to these questions and have not succeeded. Particularly the question to how is this behavior implemented in `matplotlib.legend.Legend` objects remains yet unanswered to me.

2) I have taken a look at the `matplotlib.legend.Legend` source code and I can see that the function `matplotlib.legend.Legend.get_texts()` returns a `silent_list` object, which apparently is just a list object with an overridden `__repr__` method. Still does not help me get the understanding that I am missing.

3) I am aware of the bunch of higher-level methods in `matplotlib.legend.Legend` objects that allow me to modify the legend in many/all possible ways. I though just want to understand how the mechanism works under the hood.

Thanks very much in advance for your time and help.

Comment: [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: I suspect that simply `.legend()` returns a distinct object each time. You could probably test that out easily.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the attribute machinery. You're just getting different objects from the `legend()` call each time. These objects have different attributes, so screwing with one `legend()` return value doesn't automatically affect another.

Comment: Indeed, `.legend()` creates a new instance. This is by design; you may want to update your plot, and just call `.legend()` again, which will produce a new updated legend for you. To obtain an *existing* legend, best use a handle in the first place, `leg = ax.legend()` and use it later on, or, if that is not possible, use `ax.get_legend()` to obtain the existing legend.